# TestNG, factory and parametrized Test description

Tags: java, testing, testng, factory, parameterized

I just learned that I can nest TestNG factories. Yay! However I don't like that all test names are same. This is my example:

testng.xml:

```
<suite>
    <test name="TNGTST" >
        <classes>
            <class name="FactoryLevel1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

FactoryLeve1.java:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
public class FactoryLevel1 {
    @Factory
    public Object[] createTest() {
        Object[] res = new Object[3];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            res[i - 1] = new FactoryLevel2(i);
        return res;
    }
}
```

FactoryLeve2.java:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
public class FactoryLevel2 {
    int inst;
    public FactoryLevel2(int inst) {
        this.inst = inst;
    }
    @Factory
    public Object[] createTest() {
        Object[] res = new Object[10];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            res[i - 1] = new TestClass(i * inst);
        return res;
    }
}
```

TestObj.java:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class TestObj {
    int inst;
    public TestObj(int inst) {
        this.inst = inst;
    }
    @Test
    public void printMethod() {
        System.out.println("Instance: " + inst);
    }
}
```

My problem is that Intellij IDEA shows all tests with name `TNGTST [printMethod()]` and I guess Jenkins will show something similar same for all test (I don't know how does these tools obtain it). Can I somehow create my own name for tests in **non-static way**?

Answer (score 3):

Have your test classes implement `org.testng.ITest` and override `getName()` to return what you want. I believe IDEA honors this (not 100% sure, try it).

Answer (score 2):

Cedric Beust's solution is the correct one (implement `org.testng.ITest`).

the method is called **getTestName** though :

```
@Override
public String getTestName() {
    return "custom_" + i++;
}
```

IDEA 14 honors it :

[image: TstNG with description and IDEA 14]